# Allowing access based on hostname for Manager application in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

I can't get the configuration for Tomcat right to allow access to the Manager Webapp. We have configured tomcat-users.xml, manager.xml etc. When we allow access based on the IP address it works, but based on the hostname it doesn't. This is the configuration we use:

```
<Context privileged="true"
     docBase="/path/to/tomcat_home/webapps/manager">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve"
     allow="localhost|otherhostname" deny="" />
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
     allow="172\.30\.\d+\.\d+|127\.0\.0\.1"/>
</Context>
```

When I remove the RemoteHostValve we can access the manager app (jmxproxy).
Any ideas?

Regards,

Johan-Kees

Comment: Nope that's not it. tomcat-users.xml is configured correctly. When we use the RemoteAddrValve it works, so that can't be the problem. We only have a problem with the RemoteHostValve.

Comment: are you sure that the regex matches correctly your otherhostname?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the exact hostname that host is sending via http (for example with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)), put the hostname with a prefix `.` into the config and make sure that the hostname is resolvable (i.e. via DNS and/or hosts)...

For reference see:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote%20Host%20Filter
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/engine.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/migration.html#Manager_application

Comment: The servername is in the hosts file. We use a curl script on the same server, so resolving should not be an issue (I think)

Comment: @JohanKees I can't try this myself currently... please check the links.. the client's browser could be sending a somehow differing hostname via http - thus my recommendation to check with WireShark or similar...

Comment: We've read the pages, without any luck. A.f.a.k. the config above is exactly what's described on these pages. Still trying to see how the hostname resolving is done. Maybe that's the problem. Any pointers how Tomcat resolves hostnames?

Comment: @JohanKees AFAIK via the OS (i.e. per DNS and hosts)... I still think you should check what hostname is sent in the HTTP traffic from the client with Wireshark or similar (maybe the client is sending something else than you expect)